# JavaScript version of onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout for an image

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I'd like to be able to call functions for onmouseover, onmouseout, and onclick of an image, purely using javascript, not HTML. I have code that creates a dynamic list of paragraph tags on the page using purely javascript. It looks like a list but is not a list. I've also added an x image to the left of each line of the list. I'd like when that image is clicked, to call a function to remove that line. Remember the image was added via JavaScript not HTML. How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
updateAllDataDisplay(false);
function updateAllDataDisplay(addOne) {

    // Updating the entire display
    if (!addOne) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
            let a = document.createElement("p");
            let c = document.createElement("img");
            c.src = "delete_button_smallest_still.png";
            c.addEventListener('click', removeLine(`${allData[i].month}/${allData[i].day}/${allData[i].year} (${allData[i].hours}:${allData[i].mins}:${allData[i].secs}): ${allData[i].exerciseHours}. ${allData[i].food}. ${allData[i].weight}. ${allData[i].mood}.`), false);
            a.appendChild(c);
            let d = document.createTextNode(" ");
            a.appendChild(d);
            let b = document.createTextNode(`${allData[i].month}/${allData[i].day}/${allData[i].year} (${allData[i].hours}:${allData[i].mins}:${allData[i].secs}): ${allData[i].exerciseHours}. ${allData[i].food}. ${allData[i].weight}. ${allData[i].mood}.`);
            a.appendChild(b);    
            document.body.appendChild(a); 
        }

    // Updating the last item of the display
    } else if (addOne) {
        let a = document.createElement("p");
        if (allData.length > 0) {
        let b = document.createTextNode(`${allData[allData.length - 1].month}/${allData[allData.length - 1].day}/${allData[allData.length - 1].year} (${allData[allData.length - 1].hours}:${allData[allData.length - 1].mins}:${allData[allData.length - 1].secs}): ${allData[allData.length - 1].exerciseHours}. ${allData[allData.length - 1].food}. ${allData[allData.length - 1].weight}. ${allData[allData.length - 1].mood}.`);
        a.appendChild(b);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener`

Look at the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: For some reason I have to type the function to execute upon a mouse click without the parenthesis. So I circumvented by making a global variable that could be modified in place of passing arguments. Now I'm facing a different problem. I'm having trouble removing the paragraph element which includes the small image and the line of text from the document.body. The code for how the image and line of text is added to the body of the page is in my original post. Any help with this?

Comment: It won't let me edit my comment. But my goal is: I'm trying to pass data to the function called upon 'click' that identifies document.body.currentChild of when the line of the image and text was created for the purpose of deleting that line from the document.body